# RecyclerAdapter not loading data unless I refresh

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

**This is how I initialize my adapter in my main FeedActivity:**

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
FeedAdapter adapter = new FeedAdapter(FeedActivity.this, retrieveYeets());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**This is my error:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
    at com.yitter.feed.FeedAdapter.getItemCount(FeedAdapter.java:478)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3170)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3067)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3518)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:598)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:107
```

It's complaining about the following code in my FeedAdapter:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mYeets.size();
}
```

I have no clue why my list is empty. Obviously, there's a NullPointerException in my list somehow, but it's just not obvious. It might have to do with the positioning of the elements in my list. Anybody have suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies here

```
public FeedAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> yeets) {
        super();

        mYeets = yeets;
        mContext = context;
        this.adapter = this;

        profilePictureImageLoader = new ImageLoader(new ProfilePictureFileCache(mContext));
    }
```

you forgot appending 'this' in the beginnig

```
public FeedAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> yeets) {
        super();

        this.mYeets = yeets;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.adapter = this;

        profilePictureImageLoader = new ImageLoader(new ProfilePictureFileCache(mContext));
    }
```

Comment: The solved the problem right away. Thanks a lot man. I was wracking my brain over this one.

Comment: Actually I must have had a build error or something, showing me a previous build, because now when I test it I get an new exception: ``java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference``, complaining about ``@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mYeets.size();
    }``

Comment: @bluemunch did you check you are passing a valid list to your adapter? before sending a list to adapter log its size or its value. According to this exception your list object was null.